# Code for finding the complex solution of an equation containing a tangent and a complex number

Tags: python

We are going to use the formula for calculating the input impedance found in transmission line theory. The formula is as follows, and we are trying to find ZL. The remaining variables are received as input. I used the sympy module to solve the equations.
*variables are entered arbitrarily.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTPPk.png)

As a result of the code below, the alarm said "TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float".

```
import sympy as sy
import math

#calculate beta
pi = sy.pi.evalf()
freq = 20*10**6 #float(input('frequency[MHz]='))
lamb = 2.99792458*10**8/freq  #2.99792458*10**8[ms-1]
beta = 2*pi/lamb

#input values
z0 = 50 #float(input('Z0[ohm]='))
leng = 0.5 #float(input('length[m]='))
zin = 50 #complex(input('Zin[ohm]='))

#Zin equation
zl = sy.Symbol('zl')
tan = math.tan(beta*leng)
print('tan=',tan)
a = sy.solveset(zin,z0*(complex(zl,z0*tan))/(complex(z0,zl*tan)))
print(a)
```

Through input variables(frequency, z0, length, zin), derive the ZL(maybe complex).

Comment: Well, how do you want to convert zl to float? since it's object with string representation.

Comment: If you debug the zl Symbol you can see that there is False to is_number/float/point etc. So you cannot convert it just like that.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question. However, it would be nice if zl were expressed as a complex number or float.